# How to stream webcam and record at the same time on linux?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, html5-video, video-capture

I am trying to run a webcam as a IP cam using a Single Board Computer like raspberry. I trying to stream on a web browser and hoping to record the stream on the SBC as well and not on the client side.

I found out that "mjpg streamer" can be used to either stream or record. Anyway to do this both at the same time. Is there any program that can do that on raspbian or armbian? Can I also limit the file size as well?

Comment: You might look at using FFmpeg and output HLS, where you're effectively recording in chunks which are used for streaming... so you get both functions at once.

Comment: Hi thanks for the lead. I found out that a software called motion can do it as well and its easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the program motion is very suitable for this use.

Hope this answer helps anyone looking for the same thing.

- to elaborate more.

The program I used is motion
https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html

ALl you need is just to configure the configuration file and start motion, It works what I needed. I can record and stream it at the same time. you can tweak it to your needs.

Comment: You should elaborate in your answer more, perhaps with a link to what you're using and the script or command line for doing so.